# Predictive model for meeting SLA

Tags: regression

I have a big data environment in which tickets are solved by thousands of associates, across departments. There are multiple steps to solve the tickets and one ticket can go to multiple associates. Sometimes it can be iterative also. Each ticket has a determined SLA.

Question: Want to create a predictive model, of when a particular ticket is likely to breach an SLA, based on number of steps it has gone through, person/department it goes to or any other variable.

Comment: So that we can understand your situation, please tell us what an "SLA" means, what a "determined SLA" would be, and how that might be related to "breaching" an SLA.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, but I believe the "SLA" tryinghard is referring to is Service Level Agreement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement

tryinghard, You could use a regression approach where you first predict the number of days it will take to resolve the ticket based on the variables you determine are relevant.  From there, compare the predicted days-to-resolve to the SLA to determine if the ticket is likely to go out of SLA.

You could also use a binary classification approach where, based on the variables provided, the algorithm will predict if particular ticket will fall into an out-of-SLA group or an in-SLA group, but will not give you an estimate of days-to-resolve.

There are multiple options for both regression and classification. As far as being able to tell you exactly which approach/algorithm to use, that would require more information than what you provided (and probably some sample data).

If you are new to this sort of analysis, I recommend the book "An Introduction to Statistical Learning: with Applications in R" from Springer Texts, which can be found on Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Statistical-Learning-Applications-Statistics/dp/1461471370/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1414521961&sr=1-1&keywords=an+introduction+to+statistical+learning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461471370).